# Para que serve uma função especificamente em C?

Tags: c, funções, característica-linguagem

Para que serve uma função em C, qual sua utilidade?

Comment: Mais precisamente? Resumir o número de linhas de código! E garantir melhor eficiência e deixa o código mais limpo.

Comment: vlw,obrigado aí

Answer (score -1):

Funções são elementos-chave da linguagem C. É o que permite que a linguagem seja modular.

Cada função é composta de linhas de enunciado, que realizam operações diversas ou declaram estruturas de dados em memória RAM.

Uma função tem:

- um tipo de retorno
- nenhum, um ou mais parâmetros
- escopo próprio

Comment: obrigado pela informação